# Edit hoverinfo of a stacked bar chart with plotly

Tags: r, bar-chart, plotly

I am having some trouble getting plotlys `hoverinfo` attribute to display just a single part of one bar of a stacked bar chart. To be more precise, here is a small example from the plotly Homepage:

```
library(plotly)

y <- c('giraffes', 'orangutans', 'monkeys')
SF_Zoo <- c(20, 14, 23)
LA_Zoo <- c(12, 18, 29)
data <- data.frame(y, SF_Zoo, LA_Zoo)

plot_ly(data, x = ~SF_Zoo, y = ~y, type = 'bar', orientation = 'h', name = 'SF Zoo',
             marker = list(color = 'rgba(246, 78, 139, 0.6)',
                           line = list(color = 'rgba(246, 78, 139, 1.0)',
                                       width = 3))) %>%
  add_trace(x = ~LA_Zoo, name = 'LA Zoo',
            marker = list(color = 'rgba(58, 71, 80, 0.6)',
                          line = list(color = 'rgba(58, 71, 80, 1.0)',
                                      width = 3))) %>%
  layout(barmode = 'stack',
         xaxis = list(title = ""),
         yaxis = list(title =""))
```

If I move the mouse over one bar, then both labels are shown:

[image]

Is there a way to just show the label of the grey bar when I move the mouse over the grey bar, and the pink label when moving the mouse over the pink bar, and so on?

Comment: If I remember clearly on the graphs I have made in Plotly you just click on that third big-wide arrow from the plotly logo, it makes it a single hover. The double arrow to its right makes it show both data sets in the bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must change the hovermode from "Compare data on hover" to "Show closest data on hover".

To achieve this programatically you must set the `hovermode` attribute to `closest` (https://plot.ly/r/reference/#layout-hovermode).

For R I think you must add something like this:
`layout(hovermode = 'closest')`

If you want to switch this manually in the generated plot you can do it as sconfluentus commented under your question: Just click left on the double-arrow modebar button.

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I was looking for! You saved me hours of searching. :-)

Comment: Not sure when it started, but with plotly version 4.9.0 you need to use `layout(hovermode = 'compare')`