# Plotly modify hovermode data

Tags: python-3.x, plotly, plotly-dash

I have a data frame with columns `['run_id','timestamp','pass','fail','no_run']`.
I am generating a stacked bar from it.
which looks like
[image]

Currently I am generating this stacked bar with x axis as `timestamp` and y axis as `pass/fail/no_run`.
The figure layout has `hovermode` as 'x'.

I would like a way to modify this graph so that when I hover on a bar, instead of showing timestamp in `x` axis, it should show `'run_id'`.

I don't want to change the x axis to `run_id` while generating the bar chart, it has to be timestamp, but I need a way to modify this hover data.

Comment: This seems like a similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43665727/edit-hoverinfo-of-a-stacked-bar-chart-with-plotly

Comment: No, I need to change the data label on x axis when hovered over a bar when `hovermode=x`